# Using string literal types and string literals to parametrize objects with certain keys and access them

Tags: typescript, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to build a wrapper around [redux-toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createReducer) create reducer and createAsyncThunk. My objective is to strongly type the accepted store state but keep it parameterizable and with good type inference.

The created reducer expects that certain keys with certain suffixes exist on the store state, and I want to enforce this with typings. The key suffixes are known, but the key prefixes are supposed to be provided to the function. For that reason I am using string literal types to construct the type of the keys and shape the state type to have those keys.

I think I achieved mostly what I want, but now I'm facing a problem where I can not modify the state.
If I try to spread it, typescript complains that `Spread types may only be created from object types.ts`. If I try to access the key on the object directly typescript just says that I can not use that type to index the generated state type.

Here is a simplified version of the function:

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createReducer } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

type LoadingStates<Prefix extends string> = {
  [key in `${Prefix}Pending`]: boolean;
} &
  {
    [key in `${Prefix}Error`]: string | null;
  };

type Arguments<State, Args, Returned, Prefix extends string> = {
  actionName: string;
  prefix: Prefix;
  payloadCreator: (args: Args) => Promise<Returned>;
  initialState: State & LoadingStates<Prefix>;
};

export function createAsyncReducer<
  State,
  Args,
  Returned,
  Prefix extends string
>({
  actionName,
  prefix,
  payloadCreator,
  initialState,
}: Arguments<State, Args, Returned, Prefix>) {
  const errorKey = `${prefix}Error` as const;
  const pendingKey = `${prefix}Pending` as const;
  const action = createAsyncThunk(actionName, payloadCreator);

  const reducer = createReducer(initialState, (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(action.pending, (state) => {
      state[pendingKey] = true; // Type '`${Prefix}Pending`' cannot be used to index type...
      state[errorKey] = null;
    });
    builder.addCase(action.rejected, (state, { error }) => {
      return {
        ...state, // Spread types may only be created from object types.
        [pendingKey]: false,
        [errorKey]: error.message || "Unknown error",
      };
    });
  });

  return {
    action,
    reducer,
  };
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-kG6MyoO7Nk2x2uz2u231eC4oxtbhCCQKNQaGTl5DoWgGKGcdYI1hoDSdkle2WZFweKutcwDQ+oCSY-zBWmj3ASfVKGAdR2B4OlYhiYskgAoCQKgAA6ax8XbNA9x9Ig4IHGx7AYEkwmYMCIK6HofmYZJMMiYcqlXcJKDQBFiLw7Bkh4KZKNXVZ1no-gryIhpAOAngEPYJCWVQjU4PQeQ0BBF4-0Y38kBY6BuPpbpiLgdAc0GSD1LgvT5IDdSUnIod0lqIQBRZQz1OYltKLqJT4JOPA8AwOwzEWZZxAAVVoIgIAAd0GRzxGsrYuL4Hith4rpNI5NSvX3az7yNAMFT4fQgA)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a type-safe solution, but everything works. It was as easy as saying that state is extending type object, then the spread is allowed. It will not allow to access the state properties using the generated keys thogh:

```
export function createAsyncReducer<
  State extends object,
  Args,
  Returned,
  Prefix extends string
>({
  actionName,
  prefix,
  payloadCreator,
  initialState,
}: Arguments<State, Args, Returned, Prefix>) {
```